# Get the Main Activity Class name from a single package name. How?

Tags: android, android-activity

Just I want to gain the main launcher class name from a " single" package name. I spent almost the whole day searching and searching for a solution, but !! :(
Regards

Comment: Please feel free to explain in greater detail what your problem is.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have this package: com.abc.def and I need to get the main class name that was declared in the manifest as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: Down-vote !!! You're like me someday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is, on `PackageManager`, [use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29). However, bear in mind that:

- This may return from `CATEGORY_INFO`, instead of `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, if the app has an `ACTION_MAIN` activity for `CATEGORY_INFO`
- This will only return activities with `ACTION_MAIN`, which usually is used in tandem with `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, though there's no hard requirement for that
- This can return `null`, if there is no such activity

If either of the first two limitations are a problem for you, call `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`, where you supply an `Intent` that identifies `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` and your desired package, and see what you get back. However, once again, there may not be any activities in `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` for a given package.

Comment: yeah,  that what I need, that with the action_MAIN, just to use it in the ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(package, package.class) ;